# JS code in HTML included with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using .html() to load a part of a code into an overlay div with jQuery. It works fine, until my HTML insert contains some sort of JS include:

```
<script>someFunction</script>
```

Suddenly my code stops functioning in FF, Opera and Safari. IE does just fine. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stops functioning"?  Does the HTML fail to be appended to your document?  Does the embedded script not fire?

Comment: do any errors show up in FF? Firebug?

Comment: @Ben Blank The page breaks entirely, because the <script> seems to be causeing a problem when that overlay is appended to <body>

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript script is inside of a `script` tag on the page, then anywhere `</script>` appears, even inside of a string, will close the script block.  Try putting your script inside of an external file instead.  If that doesn't work, you can do some trickery, like having a string like this:

```
"<script>/* Do stuff */</sc" + "ript>"
```

Comment: I use straight HTML. Do you say I need to write this string with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this code on a simple jQuery based page, which is similar to what you are doing:

```
$(document.body).append('<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello");</script>')
```

And it worked. I suspect that your `someFunction` code may have an error in it. Maybe you can post the code in question?

Comment: <td><script>DateInput('orderdate', true, 'DD-MON-YYYY')</script></td>  When I remove this script line everything works great.

Comment: does adding the "type" to the opening tag like in my code do anything? like this: `<script type="text/javascript">`. Also a semicolon at the end of the function call, throw that in for good measure.

Comment: Noup, didn't help. I am afraid I'll have to use different script. I this is something in the class. i took a look with FireBug and see something like: orderdate1_Object.fixYear(this) Maybe (this) is causing the confusion... Out of ideas.

Comment: Yeah if `this` called in the wrong context it might not have the meaning that the fixYear function is expecting it to. Where does that call which includes `this` appear?

Comment: The script is creating three drop downs for date picker and each has something like onChange, onBlur etc. and those selectors have something like: orderdate1_Object.fixYear(this)

Comment: I think I'll just use one of jQuery plugins instead.